# Как отключить проверку уникальности индексов в MySQL?

Tags: mysql, индексы

У меня есть таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE `payments` (
  `id` int(9) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ...
  `payments_types_id` smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  ...
  `service_id` int(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_service_id` (`service_id`,`payments_types_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=900199076 DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251
```

Проблема касается индекса `index_service_id`. Я хочу вставить данные в таблицу без заполнения поля `service_id`, а потом обновить таблицу, сделав значение этого поля равным значению поля `id`, что обеспечит уникальность индекса `index_service_id`. На время вставки и обновления таблицы я отключаю проверку уникальности индексов:

```
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;

LOCK TABLES `payments` WRITE;

insert  into `payments`(`id`,...) values (100000000, ...), ..., (999999999, ...); //поля service_id в списке параметров нет

update `payments` set `service_id` = `id`;

UNLOCK TABLES;

/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
```

но всё равно получаю ошибку:

> Query: insert into `payments`(`id`, ...
>
> Error Code: 1062 Duplicate entry '0-0' for key 'index_service_id'

В чём причина ошибки? Почему она происходит даже после отключения проверки уникальности индексов? Или как правильно отключить эту проверку?

**UPD**

Кроме того, очень хотелось бы сделать это без изменения схемы таблицы, если это возможно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Документация](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_unique_checks) про `unique_checks`:

> Setting this variable to 0 does **not require** storage engines to ignore duplicate keys. An engine is still permitted to check for them and issue duplicate-key errors if it detects them.

Эта настройка - рекомендация для storage engine, а не требование.

Mysql штука странная, но, к счастью, проверку уникальных ограничений так просто как проверку внешних ключей отключить не получится. Поэтому используйте нормальные подходы, принятые и для остальных баз данных.

1. Разрешить NULL, например. Но на большой табличке - не в курсе, как сейчас у mysql, можно ли удалить ограничение not null без пересборки таблицы.
2. удалить уникальный индекс, вставить данные, создать уникальный индекс обратно. Судя по допустимости использования LOCK TABLE WRITE, это не OLTP нагрузка. Затраты времени на пересборку индекса - в зависимости от того, какая часть данных обновляется, а какая остаётся.
3. подготовить необходимые данные в temporary table, затем сделать insert .. select из временной таблицы в реальную.

Последний пункт более интересный, не требующий снимать not null только ради записи и не надо пересобирать индекс. Вариант простой и быстрый, lock table вообще не нужен. Но есть одна большая сложность, связанная с тем, что вы хотите сделать `service_id = id`: у mysql нет штатной возможности получить заранее список id. Насколько это критично?

Можно выкрутиться вот таким хаком:

```
LOCK TABLES `payments` WRITE;

-- получаем на приложение следующее значение AI
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_name = 'table_name'
    AND table_schema = DATABASE( ) ;

ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT=(текущее_значение с прошлого шага + объём необходимых добавленных строк);

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Т.е. резервируем нужного объёма пул ai, которые можем использовать при записи (при этом поле id надо указывать и считать самостоятельно)

```
insert  into `payments`(`id`,`service_id`,`payments_types_id`) values (:ai, :ai, :type), (:ai+1, :ai+1, :type),...;
```

Можно в будущем внезапно получить проблемы с изменением параметром сервера, например, `auto_increment_increment`. И вновь table lock там, где он нафиг не нужен.

Иначе, надо понимать природу значения service_id и payments_types_id. Например, может быть вам допустимо использовать простую последовательность чисел, например, отрицательных на время записи - service_id же не объявлен как `unsigned`, а auto_increment в вашей таблице будет только положительным.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Не поняла только про "у mysql нет штатной возможности получить заранее список id"... При вставке данных `id` вставляется также явно, `insert`'ом, а потом, уже другим запросом, я делаю `update` (`service_id = id`)...

Comment: Это про то, что вручную поле с автоинкрементом вставлять нежелательно?

Comment: Если вы вставляете id всегда явно, тогда зачем поле объявлено auto_increment? Если оно именно auto_increment - то да, вставка значений явным образом - неочевидное и потому нежелательное действие. Фраза эта про то, что, например, у postgresql можно вызвать функцию nextval и таким образом зарезервировать сколько нужно id для записей перед выполнением insert и сразу сформировать корректный insert со всеми данными. А в mysql приходится вешать табличную блокировку и надеяться на постоянство поведения распределения id.

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я помню mysql, null в нем не считается равным null.
То есть вы можете этому полю присваивать null и это обойдёт проверку уникальности индекса.
То есть вам надо

```
ALTER TABLE `payments` `id` int(9) unsigned zerofill
```

и далее делаете что хотели.

Comment: А каким образом " `id` int(9) unsigned zerofill"  относится к NULL?

Comment: ну так нет NOT NULL опции, теперь можно null туда писать

Comment: Проблема в том, что в таблицу вставляется очень много записей, поэтому этот вариант мне скорее всего не подходит...